# How To Properly Display SVG image when converting HTML to PDF Using Reportlab

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, reportlab

I have been playing with Reportlab and Django all day today, and I finally have it working with the help of this SO issue earlier today...[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565679/how-to-incorporate-reportlab-with-django-class-based-view/54566002#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565679/how-to-incorporate-reportlab-with-django-class-based-view/54566002#_=_)  The output is now being produced as a PDF as expected.  However, I can't get an image to display when the output is produced as a PDF.  Nothing renders.

I have tried investigating my URLS, my absolute URLs in my settings.py file and nothing.  I've noticed I can't get my template to pick up any of my static settings, yet the rest of my project is working fine with the same references.  I also found this very similar SO issue, but can't seem to determine the actual fix....[html template to pdf with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260907/html-template-to-pdf-with-images)

My utils.py file...

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

My HTML template file...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-weight: 200;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .header {
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: center;
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 100;
               /* text-align: right;*/
               padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
            }
            .title span {
                color: #007cae;
            }
            .details {
                padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
                text-align: left !important;
                /*margin-left: 40%;*/
            }
            .hrItem {
                border: none;
                height: 1px;
                /* Set the hr color */
                color: #333; /* old IE */
                background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img class="logo3" src="/book/author.svg" >
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='header'>
                <p class='title'>Invoice # </p>
            </div>
        <div>
        <div class='details'>
            Bill to: {{ customer_name }} <br/>
            Amount: {{ amount }} <br/>
            Date: 
            <hr class='hrItem' />
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the view....

```
class SomeDetailView(DetailView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = 'pdf/invoice.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add extra context if needed
        return context

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        pdf = render_to_pdf(self.template_name, context)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

I am trying to get the author.svg image to appear on the PDF but no luck as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of trial and error I gave up on the SVG approach for now...and instead opted to use a PNG file.  I found this SO that gave me the answer...[django - pisa : adding images to PDF output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179958/django-pisa-adding-images-to-pdf-output...It) was as simple as referencing the attribute in my model via the django template as shown below:

I include a default location in my model.  I experimented with a PNG and an SVG.  The PNG worked but the SVG did not.  Either way this solves my issue.